# How do I make sure I'm using the same M file everywhere?

Tags: matlab, import

I'm creating a Matlab Library for some project. The library will have a fixed structure. What I want is that a specific m file, say `...\dir\subdir1\func1.m`, will always call another file `...\dir\subdir2\func2.m`. I tried putting this in the beginning of `func1` :

```
addpath('c:\dir\subdir2')
```

But it has two main faults:

1. If I move `dir` to another server tomorrow, it won't work
2. If somehow there is another directory with a function named `func2`, how can I tell which of the two it is using?

What do you say?

Comment: Will the "func2.m" file always be in the same subdirectory?

Comment: Yes. Structure is the same. Only `dir` might change place in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. Use packages. This allows you to create a namespace using a particular directory structure. E.g., if you have a function `func1.m` in a directory `+subdir1` then you can call this from `func2.m` in another directory using the syntax `subdir1.func1(...)` provided that the parent directory to the `+subdir1` directory is in the MATLAB path. See the MATLAB documentation on packages for more information.
2. Use `private` functions. Solution (1) isn't 100% foolproof. It's still subject to path modifications and nothing prevents the user from changing the path to call another `func1` in a different package with the same name. If you want to be absolutely sure a particular function named `func1` gets called, place it in a subdirectory to the calling function called `private`. If there are multiple functions on the path with the same name, the `private` function takes precedence. In the current example this means you would have `./dir/subdir2/func2.m` call `func1` located in `./dir/subdir2/private/func1.m`.

Comment: THNX! As for solution (2), all it takes is to put the function under a directory called `private`?

Comment: I've been using the 'package' solution and it's working fine, but it has some odd features to it. Where can I read a good explanation of what is it that actually happen when I declare a library to be a package, and how it is being called in run-time? @Michael J

Answer (score 0):

You can add paths as relative,

```
addpath ( '../subdir2' )
```

What I do is in the root of my toolbox - I have the code:

```
addpath ( genpath ( pwd ) )
```

That will add all directories from the root (`dir`) in your example.  This is in essence an installation script.

You still have the potential for name clashes, if you want you could probably utilise the capability:

```
mfilename
```

inside you mfile to check the local dir structure (i.e. is it in `\dir\subdir2`

Comment: But I'm running from `subdir1`, so `genpath(pwd)` returns only the subdirectories of `subdir1`, which `subdir2` is not one of them!

Comment: Lots of ways to resolve this one way:  `addpath ( genpath ( '../subdir2' ) )`

Comment: How does it know to find `subdir2` , which is outside 'subdir1`?

Comment: This assumed that your directory structure is consistent (you stated it was) and that you are running from `subdir1`.  FYI: I would advise against assuming the working directory (user can change this easily).

Comment: That's actually a helpful warning. So how do I make sure it always uses `func1` as a "dependancy"

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer - to 100% guarantee you need to change your dir structure - e.g. use a `private` folder.  Note: the downside of this is that no function (from a different location) will be able to see `func2`